# how to give properties and methods to objects inside a movieclip with reference to frame label/number in actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

there is a movieclip named movie with instance name movie.Inside this movie there is a textbox in frame 1.I want to  give properties and methods to that textbox.

like this

```
this.movie[1].tbox.text="helo";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but if you are using a document class I recommend you to first declare:

```
public var movie:MovieClip;
```

Then you can access the properties of the textfield like this:

```
TextField(movie.tbox).text = "hello";
```

Otherwise this will do the job:

```
this.movie.tbox.text="helo";
```

Comment: Since it is in frame 1 this will work. My advice to you is to avoid putting intances on other frames than the first one.

Comment: that i know.If u have any idea?

Comment: Well, my idea is what I just posted, have you tried it? If you have to adress a specific frame I suggest you use the addFrameScript-function:(http://blog.newmovieclip.com/2007/04/30/add-a-frame-script-addframescript-dynamically-in-flash-cs3/

Comment: there is a method in this we declare and add objects at the 1st frame itself and visibility set to 0....

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your problem, try to explain it better.